# jQuery WYSIWYG editor plugins with HTML5 support?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, font-size

After a while looking around on the web i seems can't find any jQuery wysiwyg editors that support html5 formating. Almost every plugin out there use `<font font-size="x">text</font>`
or `<big>text</big>`.

Both of those are not supported in HTML5. So i would like to kindly ask if anyone know any wysiwyg editor that uses `<style>` tag to format things.

I really love CLEditor but again there's that `<font>` tag formating or maybe someone could edit original code of CLEditor to use `<span style="font-size:XXpx">` instead.

**EDIT:** I would actually go without jQuery one even if there is some lightweight standalone javascript wysiwyg.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CKEditor allows configuration of its styling functionality. For instance:

```
config.coreStyles_bold = { element : 'span', attributes : {'style': 'font-weight:bold'} };
```

With this, you can override the default browser behavior which may use unwanted `font` tags, as well as semantic tags like `strong` or frowned-upon (but legal) style tags like `b`. It also allows similar configuration for custom styles, and any attributes (like `class`) you choose.

Another approach, if you don't find an editor that has the level of sanitization you'd prefer, would be to be more permissive with the client-side editor, processing the input with a translator/whitelist sanitizer* on the server.

* For example, [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) (PHP). I've used this together with CKEditor and I'm quite satisfied.

Comment: CKEditor look really nice and also it has jquery adapter. Thanks for pointing me to that. If i don't find anything else i'll use this.